# Importing Outlook Data File From Network Folder Error

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am trying to add an Outlook Data File from our server. This has worked on both Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013. The process to add is:

- File
- Account Settings
- Account Settings
- Data File Tab
- Add

I search for the desired data file, which is on our network and click open.

I am getting the following error:

`You can't store Outlook data files under the AppData folder. Please choose another folder.`

I have noticed that if I copy this file to a local directory on the workstation, I can add it successfully, but not from a network folder. I would like to use the network location for backup reasons.

Has anyone else ran into this issue? It seems that Outlook thinks the file is in the AppData directory.

Edit: To clarify, this is a .pst file, not a .ost file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Outlook 2016. If so:

```
-Home
-New Items
-More New Items
-Outlook Data File
```

Selct your .pst file and it will appear in the pane on the left.

If that doesn't work, create another .pst file on your network folder. Move the one that's giving you an error to your local computer and then move the contents to the one on the network folder. If you see any errors, you can use the scanpst tool on the old pst file to repair it.

Comment: Yes, I am using Outlook 2016. I have tried the process you have suggested and I get the same error. It's like Outlook thinks the file is in AppData

Comment: I've edited my answer with another way to do it that has worked for me in the past.

Comment: I think that was the same instructions, no? Anyways, I still get the same error.

Comment: It's there now. Forgot to click the "Save Edits" button.

Comment: I was able to create a new file on the network drive. I will try to transfer all of the contents and get back to you. Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: You are welcome. You can also try the scanpst on the old file if it gives you any errors. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you. This solution worked!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71967/discussion-between-nasir-riley-and-chase-ernst).